# When sharing a careers ad in a Facebook message, wrong preview icon is pulled

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, facebook

A super minor thing (and perhaps a Facebook bug), but...

When sharing a SO Careers job post on Facebook, it uses the intended OpenGraph image thingy, which is the careers logo:

[image]

But when I share it in a message, it chooses the generic careers placeholder with Joel's example profile:

[image]

I have no idea where Facebook pulls that image from, though. It doesn't seem to be linked from the job ad.

Comment: It's on the sidebar if you're not logged into Careers. Looks like it's getting filled in because that's the only image on the page.

Answer (score 2):

So according to this, [How does Facebook Sharer select Images and other metadata when sharing my URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images), we're pretty much at the mercy of Facebook.

If should default to using the company logo if available. In your case, since no logo is available, Facebook kinda makes up it's own mind on what picture to use.